# How to add table from data base to current MVC 5 context

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I'm setting up a new server with **MVC 5.2.4.0** in **ASP.NET**. I the database on a **SQL server** in a virtual machine and with the initial ASPNET tables for users my project works great.

My problem is that a have developed the database in a SQL script to execute it in the *SQL Server* with the *SQL Server Management* and I could not find a how to import the new tables to the current *context*.

I have tried to create a **ADO.NET** Entity Data Model but it creates a new *context*. It works but I'm not sure that it's correct because I think that is better to have all in one context.

I expected to know if is better to have many context in one database conextion or is better to have one context for each database conexion and if is the last one how to do it.

Comment: This is clearly described in [the ASP.NET MVC tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application). SSMS is a client tool, it has nothing to do with MVC

Comment: As for contexts, they aren't *connections*. They represent a single model or Unit of Work if you will. They *use* connections when they need to do so. A context should contain only the *entities* needed to fulfill a scenario. You can have multiple contexts per application

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks you, I do not have a clear understanding of the concept of context but now it makes more sense to me.